# I need to get the specific data inside an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, react-tsx

Hi I created a form which is returning the following data

```
autocomplete: Array(2)
0: {CD_PESSOA: 34063, NM_GUERRA: 'JOSIANE TAVARES'}
1: {CD_PESSOA: 35354, NM_GUERRA: 'J B MARTINS DE}
```

I need to get only the CD_PESSOA, and not all the fields

This is my code

```
 const addCliente = (data: any) => console.log(data)

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(addCliente)}>
        <section>
          <label>MUI Autocomplete</label>
          {/* {NameCliente.map(person => (
           */}
          <Autocomplete
            multiple
            options={NameCliente}
            getOptionLabel={(option: Option) => option.NM_GUERRA}
            onChange={(e, options) => setValue('autocomplete', options)}
            renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} />}
          />
        </section>

        <button
          type="submit"
          className="inline-flex items-center px-2.5 py-1.5 border border-transparent text-xs font-medium rounded shadow-sm text-white bg-[#9a8e74] hover:bg-[#b5aa92] focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
        >
          GRAVAR
        </button>
      </form>
```

Can anyone tell me how I filter to get only the CD_PESSOA, I need to make a post only with this ID, and not with all the information that is in the array

Answer (score 0):

You can map your array (check link for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to array that is going to have only object/values you require, so for example:

```js
const array = [
  {CD_PESSOA: 34063, NM_GUERRA: 'JOSIANE TAVARES'},
  {CD_PESSOA: 35354, NM_GUERRA: 'J B MARTINS DE}' }
]
console.log(array); 
/*
[{
  "CD_PESSOA": 34063,
  "NM_GUERRA": "JOSIANE TAVARES"
}, {
  "CD_PESSOA": 35354,
  "NM_GUERRA": "J B MARTINS DE}"
}] 
*/
const mappedArray = array.map((obj) => ({CD_PESSOA: obj.CD_PESSOA}));
console.log(mappedArray);
/*
[{
  "CD_PESSOA": 34063
}, {
  "CD_PESSOA": 35354
}] 
*/
```

You can as well map your entry array to array of values instead of objects:

```js
const valueArray = array.map((obj) => (obj.CD_PESSOA));
console.log(valueArray); //[34063, 35354]
```